# Where is main menu quick launcher in MATE Desktop 1.14.1?

Tags: mint, ubuntu-mate

I tested Mint MATE 18 and the main menu had the search and quick launch feature working with MATE Desktop 1.14.1.

I just upgraded my Ubuntu MATE 16.04.1 to ver. 1.14.1 of MATE Desktop with mate-menu 5.7.1-1 and there is no main menu quick launcher. How can I get quick launcher working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quick launcher can be enabled in MATE Tweak (which is part of the default installation):

[image]

Click **Interface** and then check the box **Enable Launcher**

[image]

You will see the launcher icon appear in your indicator panel:

[image]

And when you click it you get this dialog to search:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. What I really needed is **advanced menu**, so I can press Win key, type partial application name and press Enter to launch it, without having to reach for my mouse. Your answer guided me to the right place - just one checkbox away.

Comment: @PaulJurczak ah I see... glad you found it ^_^ we have so many options, sometimes it's hard to find them all

Comment: Works: 16.04.3 Ubuntu MATE (dual boot with Windows).  `advanced menu`.

Comment: There is no such checkbox in Ubuntu Mate 18.04.

Comment: @Alexey thanks for the heads up. I'll try to update my answer when I install 18.04

Comment: Sorry, to be exact, this is on Ubuntu 18.04 with `ubuntu-mate-desktop` package.  I didn't try Ubuntu MATE, i do not know if there would be a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have the same issue using ubuntu 16.04LTS with MATE 1.16, you can install mate-menu and add it but there is a bug and every time you start it a bad error appears (already opened issue on https://bitbucket.org/ubuntu-mate/mate-menu)

Instead using ubuntu 16.10 with mate 1.16 mate menu works correctly and you can also add brisk menu https://github.com/solus-project/brisk-menu (not compatible with 16.04 version)